# VueJS $set with variable keypath

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently working on a simple filemanager component which I trigger from parent component. After selecting media in the filemanager I `$dispatch` a simple data object with 2 keys: element & media. I use element to keep track where I want the media to be appended to my current data object and media has the media information (id, type, name and so on). This setup gives me some trouble when I want to `$set` the media data to variables within my data object. The variables are locales, so: nl-NL, de-NL and so on.

```
setMediaForPage : function(data){
    if(!this.page.media[this.selectedLanguage]['id'])
    {   
        // set for all locales
        var obj = this;
        this.application.locales.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            obj.$set(obj.page.media[element.locale], data.media);
        })
    }
    else 
    {
        // set for 1 locale
        this.$set(this.page.media[this.selectedLanguage], data.media);
    }
}
```

What happens when I run this code is that the data object shows up properly in Vue Devtools data object, but the media does not show up in the template. When I switch the language (by changing the `this.selectedLanguage` value), the media does show up.

I think this has to do with the variables in the object keypath, but I'm not 100% sure about that. Any thoughts on how to improve this code so I can show the selected media in the parent component without having to change the  `this.selectedLanguage`value?

Comment: How are you showing the media? I think that your problem could be more related with Vue lifecycle, I mean put the code of the hook in which you are updating your media, if you are doing it in a hook, put the code itself to see if maybe you are trying to use some unasigned or undefined variable, etc

Comment: I have a media component, which can handle audio, video & images. I send a media property  `:media="media"` to that component which checks for the media.type - and renders the media based on that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your data structure exactly, but you can certainly use variables as the the keypath in vue, however remember that the keyPath should be a string, not an object.

If your variable that you want to use in the keypath is part of the vue, you'd do it like this:

```
obj.$set('page.media[element.locale]', data.media)
```

... because the keyPath which is a string is intelligently parsed by Vue's $set method and is of course it knows that this path is relative to the $data object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I changed my code to:

   `console.log('locale',element.locale);  obj.$set('page.media[element.locale]', data.media);`

and I do see some result, but in the $set part it seems that element.locale is not available - I get undefined in my data object where element.locale should be used. In the console.log I do see the proper locale.

Comment: I don't know why that would be. possibly because element.locale is two levels deep, whereas I have only ever used one level deep in the dynamic part of the keyPath before. Try setting `var locale = element.locale` and using that variable as the `page.media[locale]` and let me know what you find

Answer (score 0):

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        msg: "hello world",
        attr: {
          lang: {
            zh: '中文',
            en: 'english'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      $set2(obj, propertyName, value) {
        let arr = propertyName.split('.');
        let keyPath = arr.slice(0, -1).join('.');
        let key = arr[arr.length - 1];
        const bailRE = /[^\w.$]/

        function parsePath(obj, path) {
          if (bailRE.test(path)) {
            return
          }
          const segments = path.split('.')
          for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
            if (!obj) return
            obj = obj[segments[i]]
          }
          return obj
        }

        let target = parsePath(obj, keyPath);
        // console.log(target, key);
        // target[key] = value;
        this.$set(target, key, value);
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // this.$set('attr.lang.zh', '嗯');
        // this.$set2(this, 'attr.lang.zh', '嗯');
        this.$set2(this.attr, 'lang.zh', '嗯');
      }, 1000);
    }
  })
```

调用示例：this.$set2(this.attr, 'lang.zh', '嗯');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

i have also experienced similar problems，remove variables `-`,these variables `nl-NL, de-NL` change to `nlNl, deNl`
and i not use

```
obj.$set('page.media[element.locale]', data.media)
```

but

```
obj.$set('page.media.'+element.locale, data.media);
```

then it work